# How to resolve Exception : jpype._jexception.ExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.Exception: Class Example not found

Tags: java, python

**Python : 2.7 - 32 bits,
Java : jdk7 - 32 bits,
JVM path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll**

**Hello.py file**

```
import jpype
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())

jpype.java.lang.System.out.println("hello world")

Ex = jpype.JClass("Example")
Exobj = Ex()
print Exobj.addImage()
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

**Example.java file in same package**

```
public class Example {
    public String addImage() {
        System.out.println("In java file");
    }
}
```

**On execution of Hello.py - python Hello.py : output is as below**

```
C:\Test>python Hello.py
hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Test\hello.py", line 6, in <module>
    Ex = jpype.JClass("Example")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jclass.py", line 54, in JClass
    raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name)
jpype._jexception.ExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.Exception: Class Example not found
```